# PDF in Preview id blurry on scrolling after upgrading to 10.9

Tags: pdf, macos, preview

I upgraded my system to 10.9 Mavericks. `Preview` works not as good as before. I have the same trouble with that [post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1650687). What will the problem be? Lack of memory? New configurations of `Preview`? I hope to use it smoothly as before. What can I do with it?

I am using Macbook Air 2013.

Comment: Do you scroll using the touchpad? I have the same problem since I've upgraded to Mavericks and it seems to be that, when scrolling, it also slightly follows the horizontal movements of my fingers. Therefore when I don't move my fingers perfectly straight, it moves the document horizontally by a pixel or two, causing the text to be blurred.

Comment: Yes, it is this problem. However, it does not look like a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a caching bug in 10.9.0. If you have not transferred any files to this computer from a another Mac (via Time Machine for example) then you should be okay.

I doubt you have an actual hardware issue or limitation. If you were running a 2007 MacBook and you performed an upgrade I would expect this before due to the grandfathering of certain files/preferences/caches.

In a fresh system and new model your issue would not be tolerated by Apple. I would suggest submitting some feedback to Apple: http://www.apple.com/feedback/ and get them aware of this issue.

If this starts to show up in other apps or with other file types then it might be a good idea to go to an Apple Store or AASP and let them do a check on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have you experienced the same issue? I downloaded Mac OS X 10.9 from the Internet because of the slow network here, and did a upgrade. Not error occurred, however some settings changed so that I have to get used to it for a few days. The only unpleasant thing for me is the blurry feature when scrolling pages with `Preview`. Will I get Apple noticed if I submit some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd share this comment, since I believe this is the case. I am on a new MBP with HD Intel 4000 and I get the a strong blur on scroll. Doesn't matter if it's Safari or Activity Monitor. However, on iMac with Radeon 6970 the blur is much less noticeable.

"I've seen this type of effect on a number of systems and hardware. I think what the software does is create a lower resolution image of the page and uses tat to display when scrolling. This lower resolution image takes less calculation to show the movement of the scroll or zoom, and possibly allows free CPU timeto calculate and pre render what is about to appear in the scroll. When the movement is stopped, it'll then do a complete screen redraw at full resolution.

This type of procedure probably comes from mobile type devices where CPU resource can be limited and a balance struck between smoothness and image quality."

Source: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1650687
Author: fisha

Also, Apple made a statement about this:
http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27218?viewlocale=en_US